# is weight of two identical objects same when they have the same exact distance from earth's surface but one is on a mountain and the other on a plane?

Tags: mass

Is the weight of two identical objects the same when they have the same exact distance from the earth's surface but one is on a mountain and the other on a plane?

The distance between the plane and the earth's surface contains only air.

Anyway can anyone test this? I have seen some documentaries where they test the weight of the same person in different heights always on a hill or mountain but I have not seen anyone doing what I ask above. When that is tested, are there any data worth observing?

Comment: Do the two objects have the same mass?

Comment: They have the same mass. That can be tested with the same object as well.

Comment: Similar questions on physics.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/458327/does-gravity-get-stronger-when-you-climb-a-mountain https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652752/does-gravity-get-stronger-the-higher-up-you-are-on-a-mountain https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374132/mountain-gravity

Comment: Rant about moderator egos removed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no astronomical question here.  This is Physics or Earth Science

Comment: I know about the ranting part and i am sorry about that. As for the voting part, it is your vote and how you choose to use it. As for the reason for using that vote, i understand. Good luck!

Comment: What kind of plane? Do you mean an aeroplane / airplane?

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant but i now think that the airplane assuming not moving but just having the same height as the mountain  will act the same as the mountain does. Only if weighing the object being on its own in that specific height might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weight of an object is the force due to gravity an object feels. Consider the force of gravity sourced by Earth's mass acting on two particles of equal mass, $m_1 = m_2$, but that are located at different heights $h$ in Earth's gravitational field, i.e. $h_1 \neq h_2$. Using Newton's second law, the force on each particle due to the gravity of Earth is,

$$ F_1 = m_1 a(h_1)$$
and
$$ F_2 = m_2 a(h_2)$$.

where m is the mass and a is the net acceleration. Since we're only considering accelerations due to gravity here, then $a$ is just the [gravitational acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration#Gravity_model_for_Earth).

$a(h)$ is a function of height from Earth's center. So, if two objects of equal mass are at different altitudes, then they will necessarily experience different gravitational acceleration, and thus have different weight. Thus, if $m_1=m_2$ and $h_1 \neq h_2$, then we may conclude that $F_1 \neq F_2$.

Comment: And the force or whatever is called that the object is acting on the mountain is cancelled out from the force that the mountain acts back to that object, right?

Comment: They do not cancel. Please examine Newton's three laws of motion: the first states that an object will remain in motion unless acted upon; the second is the statement of $F = ma$; the third is the statement that forces between two objects exist in pairs. So, using Newton's third law of motion, there is a gravitational force that is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction acting on the Earth due to the gravity of the object. These are called third law force pairs (remember, for them to be third law force pairs, they have to act on/by the same objects!).

Comment: So ask yourself as an analogy: in a car crash between a small car and a big truck, which experiences the larger force? (this might be a trick question! ;) )

Comment: I read about Newton's third law on Wikipedia ( i have not understood it 100% yet). Regarding your analogy: small car and big truck have same speed. The force that they act onto the other is proportionate to their mass thus by newton's third law, the big truck experiences larger force. That is hard to understand.

Comment: You fell into my trap! ;D Newton's third law states that the force pairs are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, so the force on the truck by the car has to be equal in magnitude to the force on the car by the truck! The difference is in the $acceleration$ that they feel: the car feels a larger acceleration since its mass is smaller but it feels the same force as the truck does. Does that make sense?

Comment: So with your object in the Earth's gravity field, the force on that object by the Earth and the force onthe Earth by that object are equal in magnitude, but the object feels a much larger acceleration than the Earth because the object is (very) less massive than the Earth.

Comment: Lastly, do not confuse these third law force pairs with your original question, which is about comparing the force on object 1 by the Earth to the force on object 2 by the Earth.

Comment: When you say Earth, you include the mountain right? Also, how can the forces by the vehicles to on another be equal in magnitude? In that sense, if we have one object of steel and an object of cotton with the same mass and height from earth's core and same speed, they should apply a force of equal magnitude to one another, right?

Comment: I did not mention a mountain. It depends on what you mean in the problem you're trying to solve. You did not define your problem rigorously enough for me to comment on it directly. In my answer, I am treating the Earth as a sphere and talking about the gravitational acceleration that objects feel at different heights from the surface of that spherical Earth. You could consider one such point to be a mountain. Try reading about third law force pairs here https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/newtlaws/Lesson-4/Identifying-Action-and-Reaction-Force-Pairs and try to solve their examples.

Comment: I understand. Read that article and is a good one. Can you explain to me in simple terms how do you understand the concept of a force? I will be grateful!

Comment: It depends on how sophisticated of a description you want. If you're at introductory level, then Newtonian mechanics is sufficient, where a force is represented by a vector defined as the time derivative of the linear momentum, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton's_second_law

Comment: If you're interested in more sophisticated treatment, you should first read about a 4-force in the theory of Special Relativity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force , and even more advanced is how that is generalized in Einstein's theory of gravitation (called General Relativity) https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/31/4/024/meta

Comment: You have been very helpful and i thank you very much for that. I do not want to waste your time anymore so thank you very much and good luck! " An Atom or Particle can only walk forward never backward" :)

Comment: PS. Related to the commend above: Forget "Time" . Time does not exist. Had to add this

Comment: This ďoes not answer the question.

Comment: It clearly did. Look above at the convo I had with the OP...... @DescheleSchilder you're clearing targeting me b/c I spoke against you yesterday, which is against site policy to seek vengeance like you're doing. Please stop or else I'll be forced to ask for moderator intervention.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, when talking about gravity, we assume the objects to be dimensionless points with all their mass concentrated in their center of mass. This makes working with gravity much easier, and it is generally a "good enough"™ approximation when the two objects are "far away"™ from each other (as is usually the case in Astronomy). If we need a little more precision, we assume that the two objects are spheres. For celestial bodies, specifically, we can add even more precision by assuming they are ellipsoids or oblate spheroids. And for even more precision, we actually have geoid models of Earth, for example.

However, for this *particular* example, the object and the Earth are *not* far away from each other, so the shape of the Earth definitely is relevant. In fact, even the *composition* of the Earth is relevant: a mountain made of aerogel and a mountain made of Uranium will behave very different.

The object on top of the mountain will have more weight, because there is "more mass" below it that is "pulling" on it due to gravity. Even two objects on two mountains that have the same shape but different density will experience a different weight.

While I don't think we have measured this on planes and mountains, we definitely have measured this on satellites. For example, on Earth, the twin [GRACE satellites](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/GRACE_and_GRACE-FO) have created "gravity maps" of Earth. Similarly, the [GRAIL satellites](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/GRAIL) have produced equivalent results for the Moon. Areas with a high concentration of mass are called [mascons](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_concentration_(astronomy)).

More narrowly, *mascon* refers to an area, where *topographically* you would *think* that gravity is *lower* than average (e.g. a depression such as a crater or a valley), but due to the density of the material the ground is made up of, the gravity is actually *higher* than average.

With regards to your specific question about standing on a mountain, here is a map of [gravity anomalies](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_anomaly) of Earth:
[image: Map of gravity anomalies of Earth]

Can you spot the Andes? Looking at the map, imagine you are standing on top of the [Aconcagua](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Aconcagua) at an elevation of 6961 m in one of the deep red areas of the anomaly map, and then you are standing in an aeroplane at the same altitude above the North Atlantic north-east of Puerto Rico or the Indian Ocean, above one of the deep blue areas of the map. You will be lighter above the Indian Ocean than above the Andes, even at the same altitude.

As mentioned above, the Earth is not a perfect sphere, it is "fatter" at the equator, so gravity and thus weight also differs with latitude: when you are standing at the equator, there is more mass below your feet than when you are standing on one of the poles, *even though* at the equator you are actually further away from the center of mass.

The Moon is one of the celestial bodies we have measured that has the most extreme "lumpy" gravity field. Its mascons are so big that there are places on the Moon where a [plumb bob](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumb_bob) will actually deflect sideways by one third of a degree!

Comment: Thank you for spending some of your time for that greatly structured answer! I look at the image with the Earth's Gravity Field Anomalies and this question pops up in my head: what is the distance that is needed to be between Earth and another object  in order for Earth's gravity field to act as one ( a single unit or without anomalies) ?  Also, can you describe in simple terms Earth's Elliptical path during its orbit around the sun? If you provide the math for it after the explanation, that would be great and really appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes the wrong answers are accepted. Great answer!